# Apache MultiViews Alternative

Tags: apache-2.2

Is their away to achieve the same effect as MultiViews does (ie 'example.com/page' points to 'example.com/page.php') using another setting in the .htaccess file? Either through mod_rewrite or another way? The hosting I'm using does not allow MultiViews.

Answer (score 0):

With mod_rewrite .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(page)$ page.php [L]
```